# Java MouseListener also detects clicks from the Robot Class

Tags: java, recursion, minecraft, mouselistener, awtrobot

I make a program that simulates a click with the Robot class when i click. So I have 2 clicks but i clicked once. My Problem is the MouseListener also detects Clicks from the Robot and the Robot always triggers the MouseListener and it doesn't stops clicking. Does anybody know how to fix this?
I use the JNativeHook Library so I can listen to global KeyStrokes. With the java.awt.MouseListener I can only detect Mouse Inputs when my window is in focus.
Here's my Code:

```
package de.fastwieac.doubleclicker.main;

// imports
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseEvent;
import org.jnativehook.mouse.NativeMouseInputListener;
import java.awt.Robot;
import java.awt.event.InputEvent;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.AWTException;

public class Main extends javax.swing.JFrame implements NativeMouseInputListener {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public Main() {
        initComponents();
    }

    private void initComponents() {

        // create instances
        panel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        rbtnOn = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        rbtnOff = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        rbtnLeft = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        rbtnRight = new javax.swing.JRadioButton();
        txtKey = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        txtHotkey = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        

        // frame properties
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("DoubleClicker");
        setResizable(false);
        setSize(new java.awt.Dimension(304, 304));

        // panel properties
        panel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 204));
        panel.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 14));

        // radio button rbtnOn properties
        rbtnOn.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 14));
        rbtnOn.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        rbtnOn.setText("On");
        rbtnOn.setSelected(true);
        rbtnOn.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                rbtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        // radio button rbtnOff properties
        rbtnOff.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 14));
        rbtnOff.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        rbtnOff.setSelected(false);
        on = true;
        rbtnOff.setText("Off");
        rbtnOff.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                rbtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        // radio button rbtnLeft properties
        rbtnLeft.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 14));
        rbtnLeft.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        rbtnLeft.setSelected(true);
        left = true;
        rbtnLeft.setText("Left Click");
        rbtnLeft.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                rbtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        // radio button rbtnRight properties
        rbtnRight.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 14));
        rbtnRight.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        rbtnRight.setText("Right Click");
        rbtnRight.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                rbtnActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        // txtKey Properties
        txtKey.setEditable(false);
        txtKey.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 204));
        txtKey.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 14));
        txtKey.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        txtKey.setText("Key:");
        txtKey.setBorder(null);

        // txtHotkey properties
        txtHotkey.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 204, 204));
        txtHotkey.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Segoe UI", 1, 14));
        txtHotkey.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 0));
        txtHotkey.setText("R");
        txtHotkey.setBorder(null);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout panelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(panel);
        panel.setLayout(panelLayout);
        panelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(panelLayout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                .addGroup(panelLayout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(85, 85, 85)
                                        .addComponent(txtKey, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 30,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                                        .addComponent(txtHotkey, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 13,
                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                                .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                                        panelLayout.createSequentialGroup().addGroup(panelLayout
                                                .createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                                                .addGroup(panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                        .addComponent(rbtnLeft, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                98, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(
                                                                javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 45,
                                                                Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                        .addComponent(rbtnRight, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                98, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                                                .addGroup(panelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
                                                        .addComponent(rbtnOn, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                98, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                                        .addPreferredGap(
                                                                javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED,
                                                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                                                        .addComponent(rbtnOff, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                                                98, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                                                .addGap(29, 29, 29)))));
        panelLayout.setVerticalGroup(panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(panelLayout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap()
                        .addGroup(panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(rbtnOn).addComponent(rbtnOff))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addGroup(panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(rbtnLeft).addComponent(rbtnRight))
                        .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                        .addGroup(panelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(txtKey, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                                .addComponent(txtHotkey, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                        javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addContainerGap(17, Short.MAX_VALUE)));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(
                panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addComponent(
                panel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE));

        pack();
    }

    private void rbtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource().equals(rbtnOn)) {
            rbtnOn.setSelected(true);
            rbtnOff.setSelected(false);
            on = true;
            if (txtHotkey.getText().length() > 1) {
                txtHotkey.setText("R");
            }
            txtHotkey.setText(txtHotkey.getText().toUpperCase());
        }

        if (e.getSource().equals(rbtnOff)) {
            rbtnOff.setSelected(true);
            rbtnOn.setSelected(false);
            on = false;
        }

        if (e.getSource().equals(rbtnLeft)) {
            rbtnLeft.setSelected(true);
            rbtnRight.setSelected(false);
            left = true;
        }

        if (e.getSource().equals(rbtnRight)) {
            rbtnRight.setSelected(true);
            rbtnLeft.setSelected(false);
            left = false;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        Logger l = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
        l.setLevel(Level.OFF);

        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        } catch (NativeHookException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        
        GlobalScreen.addNativeMouseListener(new Main());

        // JOptionPane
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Use only 1 Key as Hotkey!");

        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Main().setVisible(true);
            }
        });

    }

    private boolean left;
    private boolean on;
    private Robot robot;
    private javax.swing.JPanel panel;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton rbtnLeft;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton rbtnOff;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton rbtnOn;
    private javax.swing.JRadioButton rbtnRight;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtHotkey;
    private javax.swing.JTextField txtKey;

    @Override
    public void nativeMouseClicked(NativeMouseEvent e) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public void nativeMousePressed(NativeMouseEvent e) {
        
        if (e.getButton() == NativeMouseEvent.BUTTON1 & on == true & left == true) {
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON1_DOWN_MASK);

        }
        if (e.getButton() == NativeMouseEvent.BUTTON3 & left == false & on == true) {
            robot.mousePress(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
            robot.mouseRelease(InputEvent.BUTTON3_DOWN_MASK);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void nativeMouseReleased(NativeMouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void nativeMouseDragged(NativeMouseEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void nativeMouseMoved(NativeMouseEvent e) {

    }

}
```

Comment: Been a while since I worked with this.. can the `getSource()` method help you distinguish between your clicks and those of java.awt.Robot? If not, you'll need a workaround. Like using left-click yourself and make the Robot always right-click. (Hope I understood the problem right).

Comment: You are asking how to fix a "bug" in your implementation. I suggest wrapping the "robot" mouse press in a call to method [`invokeLater`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-). Having said that, I'm curious to know what your application does that led you to implement it using "robot" and needing to listen to mouse clicks anywhere on the desktop and not just in your application's `JFrame`.

Comment: I do it for Minecraft. The more clicks you have in Minecraft the less knockback you get. And the application duplicates my clicks.

Comment: So basically you're trying to cheat in [Minecraft](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/store/minecraft-java-edition). I have a suggestion. Use [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to bind an unused key, like F12, so that when you press F12 it simulates multiple mouse clicks. And by the way, you won't need [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) to implement my suggestion.

Comment: Why do i not need JNativeHook? Yes, i try to cheat in Minecraft and no i don't want to do it like you said because i still want to click.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a boolean value, like "clicked"? You toggle it everytime a click is triggert and only trigger another one if its true.

So you click –> its true, the bot clicks –> its false and wont click again until you click again?